# Accumulating values: for loop to Reduce

Tags: r

I have a pretty simple `for` loop the adds variable rate compound interest.  I was trying to do it in a vectorized way perhaps using `Reduce` which makes sense (which I believe is not truly vectorized).  But the attempt failed to produce the same results:

```
principal <- 10000
rates <- c(0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)
balance <- rep(NA, length(rates) + 1)
balance[1] <- principal

for (i in seq_along(rates)){
    balance[i + 1] <- balance[i] * (1 + rates[i]) 
}

## > balance
## [1] 10000.00 10300.00 10712.00 11247.60 11585.03 12048.43 12650.85
```

Here is the `Reduce` attempt:

```
growth <- function(balance, rate) {
    balance * (1 + rate)    
}

Reduce(growth, principal, rates, accumulate = TRUE)
```

But that gives:

```
## [[1]]
## [1] 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.03 0.04 0.05
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 300.03 400.04 500.05 300.03 400.04 500.05
```

This is expected as I have no way to supply a vector to `Reduce` as `rates`.  What I want is a combination between `Reduce` and `Map`.  Perhaps the `for` loop is the best approach here.  But is there an approach without?

Comment: The initial value is supposed to be the third argument, not the second.  See `args(Reduce)` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Perfect.  I've always used `Reduce` on a single vector and a function that acts on that vector.  I didn't know you could use `Reduce` in this way. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your example is too simplified. Would this suffice?

```
principal <- 10000
rates <- c(0, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)
principal*cumprod(1+rates)
## [1] 10000.00 10300.00 10712.00 11247.60 11585.03 12048.43 12650.85
```

Comment: This answers the question in a truly vectorized way +1

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you are using `Reduce` properly, it should be:

```
Reduce(growth, rates, init = principal, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1] 10000.00 10300.00 10712.00 11247.60 11585.03 12048.43 12650.85
```

Comment: This answer answers the question more generally.  An excellent answer and may be of use to others with a similar problem where `cumprod` couldn't be used.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Since you care about speed/vectorization.

```
WHILE <- function(rate = c(3,4,5,3,4,5), tuit = c(10000, rep(NA,6))){
    i <- 1
    while (i < length(tuit) ) {
      tuit[i+1]  =  tuit[i]*(1+ (rate[i]/100) )
      i = i + 1
    }
    tuit
}

FOR <- function(principle=10000, rates=c(0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)){
    balance <- rep(NA, length(rates) + 1)
    balance[1] <- principle

    for (i in seq_along(rates)){
        balance[i + 1] <- balance[i] * (1 + rates[i]) 
    }
    balance
}


REDUCE <- function(principal=10000, rates=c(0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)){
    growth <- function(balance, rate) {
        balance * (1 + rate)    
    }

    Reduce(growth, rates, init = principal, accumulate = TRUE)
}

VECTORIZED <- function(principal=10000, rates=c(0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)){
    principal*cumprod(1+rates)
}

(op <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark( 
    WHILE(),
    FOR(),
    REDUCE(),
    VECTORIZED(),
times=1000L))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added a `while` option to this so it is indeed a new answer and then benched all 4 approaches on a Win 7 machine.